# Populate JList from ArrayList<>

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist, populate

Hi i have an ArrayList where catalogo is my class. I would populate my JList of these arraylist but i can not..can you help me?

Here there's the youIng code:

```
public class YouIng {

private List<Catalogo> listaCatalogo = new ArrayList<Catalogo>();

    public YouIng(){
        Catalogo premium = new Catalogo();
        Catalogo standard = new Catalogo();
        listaCatalogo.add(premium);
        listaCatalogo.add(standard);
    }

    public List<Catalogo> getCatalogo(){
        return listaCatalogo;
    }
```

I use a GUI Class called YouIngFrame to use my program. When i click on loginButton it will show me a JList which should be populated from listaCatalogo, but it's not.

Here there's the YouIngFrame class:

```
private void loginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    card.show(mainPanel, "homePanel");
    welcomeLabel.setText("Benvenuto: " +usernameField.getText().toString());

    for(int i=0; i<youing.getCatalogo().size(); i++){
        jList.add(youing.getCatalogo().get(i));
    }    
}
```

Hope this will help you

EDIT:

Here there's my Catalogo.java:

```
public class Catalogo {

public Catalogo(){
    Categoria commedia = new Categoria();
    Categoria fantasy = new Categoria();
    listaCategoria.add(commedia);
    listaCategoria.add(fantasy);
}

private List<Categoria> listaCategoria = new ArrayList<Categoria>();

public List<Video> CercaVideo(String ParolaChiave) {
    return null;
}

public Video Search(String IDvideo, Categoria cat) {
    return null;
}

public List<Categoria> getCategorie() {
    return listaCategoria;
}

public Categoria aggiungiVideo(Video usr_video, int categoriaScelta) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Please expand your posted code such that it is a valid [mcve]. Please check out the link.

Comment: i want to populate a jList component of Catalogo elements, where Catalogo is a my personal class.

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx Never provide further details in comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: @FarazDurrani i tried your last solution but netbeans gives me same previously error  "there's no suitable method found for add(Catalogo)"

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx can you show me your Catalogo class?

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx I m very close to solving it please show me your catalogo class. I don't want someone else to take my 10 points! :P

Comment: See [*How to Use Lists*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), especially [*Writing a Custom Cell Renderer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Comment: `How show a generic Object into a Jlist component?` - the default renderer for a JList  uses the `toString()` method of your object to display a string in the JList. If you haven't implemented the toString() method you will get unreadable text. So you need to implement the toString() method. The other approach is to create a `custom renderer` for your JList. For more information on renderers read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
for(Catalogo p : listaCatalogo ){
     dlm.addElement(p.toString());
}    
JList jList = new JList(dlm);
```

And now you changed your method signature. So here is the solution according to new method of yours:

```
private void loginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
card.show(mainPanel, "homePanel");
welcomeLabel.setText("Benvenuto: " +usernameField.getText().toString());

DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();
for(Catalogo p : youing.getCatalogo() ){
 dlm.addElement(p.toString());
}    
JList<String> jList = new JList<String>(dlm);
System.out.println(jList.getModel().toString()); //TO TEST if Jlist successfully added catalogo      
}
```

And don't forget you must override `toString()` method inside class `YouIng`.

Comment: tried but still doesn't work. It doesn't show me Catalogo elements in my JList

Comment: i rewrote all my question...hope it will help you to fix my problem

Comment: catalogo.java contains an other ArrayList but that's not the problem. The problem is: How show a generic Object into a Jlist component?

Comment: I tried your last solution but JList still doesn't show me anything. I think i should see my 2 objects, premium and standard, into the jlist right??

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx do you have toString() method overridden inside class YouIng?

Comment: I create youing object in my main method. i haven't done override of toString() method. My CatalogoClass has no methods implemented yet..but i should see the 2 Catalogo objects in the Jlist anyway right?

Comment: read my edit. I added the content of my Catalogo Class. Anyway, using the System.out.println() i showed the 2 Catalogo items but not in the JList. I think the problem is the JList

Comment: in the Catalogo constructor method i create anothers 2 object of another class.

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx you can test your JList by System.out.println(jList.getModel().toString()); I am sure JList is fine. What do you get when you do this?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try to fix the problem

Comment: thanks for upvoting it and accepting it :P But the problem is not solved yet. Can you tell me what do you get when you type this: System.out.println(jList.getModel().toString()); You add that line after JList<String> jList = new JList<String>(dlm);

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx you can override toString() method in each of your class like Catalogo and Categoria in eclipse easily. Goto Source at the top left and then click on generate toString() and then check the items and then okay